# FINRA Rule for "Adjustment of Open Orders

Tags: security

FINRA members holding open orders for customers or other broker-dealers must adjust those orders on any ex-dividend date for that security, in a manner similar to the adjustments made by exchange specialists.

```
The rule applies to:
• buy limit, sell stop, or sell stop-limit order

The rule does not apply to:
• Sell limit, buy stop, or buy stop-limit orders
```

**Question**> Is there a reason why FINRA applies the rule to some orders but not others?

Answer (score 2):

On the ex-dividend date the **price of the stock should fall immediately** by more or less the amount of the dividend.  The rule is established to prevent this from triggering a bunch of orders that are contingent on falling prices without the traders intending this.  The first set of trades have the property that they execute when prices fall.

On the other hand, if the price mechanically falls at the ex-dividend date, sell limit orders (for example) will be less likely to execute than they were.  The trader has plenty of time to adjust the orders to the new price and needs not worry about them getting accidentally triggered as a result of the dividend.